# AWS Elastic Beanstalk .ebextensions not being called in in buildspec.yml

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am having an issue where I have several `.config` files in my `.ebextensions`. And my `buildspec.yml` looks as such:

```
version: 0.2

artifacts:
    files:
      - .ebextensions/**/*
phases:
  install: 
    runtime-versions:
      php: 7.4
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started on `date`
    - echo installing composer..
    - composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
```

In AWS CodeBuild, my pipeline keeps breaking because composer is trying to install packages like `ffmpeg` and `libz` that are specified in my `.ebextensions` that is never called.

My output looks as such:

```
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:19:49 Waiting for agent ping
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:19:51 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:11 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:11 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src119370068/src
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:11 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src119370068/src/buildspec.yml
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:11 No commands found for phase name: install
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:11 Processing environment variables
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:12 Selecting 'php' runtime version '7.4' based on manual selections...
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:12 Running command echo "Installing PHP version 7.4 ..."
Installing PHP version 7.4 ...

[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:12 Running command phpenv global $PHP_74_VERSION
7.4.1

[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src119370068/src
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Registering with agent
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phases found in YAML: 3
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15  INSTALL: 0 commands
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15  BUILD: 9 commands
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15  POST_BUILD: 2 commands
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Entering phase INSTALL
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Running command echo Build started on `date`
Build started on Sun May 3 12:20:15 UTC 2020

[Container] 2020/05/03 12:20:15 Running command echo installing composer..
installing composer..
```

It is installing `composer` but never installing the `ebextensions`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

CodeBuild dont understand 'ebextensions'. This directory is significant for the Elastic Beanstalk command processor only.

For CodeBuild, please run the installation commands manually in the buildspec.